# Chinese strings shown as question marks when exported as CSV file through servlet

Tags: java, excel, servlets, csv, internationalization

I am now debugging a Java servlet which does the exporting of several strings into an CSV file.

It should be pretty standard, only except that for Simplified-Chinese strings, it will be shown as question marks on resulting CSV file.

I've googled many solutions, here is the one I think most reasonable, and I have put it in my code:

```
    response.setContentType("text/csv;charset=gb18030");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("gb18030");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Contacts.csv");

    response.getWriter().write(returnString);
    response.getWriter().flush();
    response.getWriter().close();
```

However, it won't work for my case. I have replaced "gb18030" with "UTF-8", still no luck.

The input data comes in the following way:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
CsvExporter.writeCsvFile(dataRecordList, f_csvExportMappings, baos);
String returnString = new String(baos.toByteArray());
```

Could experts offer some suggestions of similar problems? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://superuser.com/questions/280603/how-to-set-character-encoding-when-opening-excel) ?

Comment: Where is `returnString` taken from? if it's coming from an input stream, did you also open it as `UTF-8`?

Comment: @BackSlash, updated the code. There is no explicit definition of UTF-8 in it.

Comment: Did you try `String returnString = baos.toString("UTF-8")`?

Comment: @BackSlash, Trying now with the suggested code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the charset used in your input stream.
Usually, we use "GBK" or "GB2312" for Chinese charset encoding.

Comment: will this affect other non-Chinese languages?

Comment: [GBK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBK) is an extension of the GB2312 character set for simplified Chinese characters, used in the People's Republic of China. So use it only when you have Chinese characters in you String or input.

Answer (score -1):

Try reading `returnString` as UTF-8:

```
String returnString = baos.toString("UTF-8");//or whatever charset you need
```

Then, instead of writing the byte array, try directly writing the string:

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");//or whatever charset you need
PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();  
writer.println(returnString);
```

Comment: @BackSlah, the problem still persists after modification.